# how to use state dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

i have state like this

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  this.state = {
    activeRegion: listProvince,
    listProvince: [],
    listCity: [],
    listRegion: [],
  }
}
```

and how to use state by other state ?

so the data that i gonna use in flatlist is based on activeRegion

when value in activeRegion is ListCity
data used in flatlist is this.state.listcity

and so on

```
  <FlatList
    data={this.state.{this.state.activeregion}}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (this.renderItem())
   />
```

how to achieve this goals ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the simplest answer to keep in line with what you are doing is to use bracket notation `data={this.state[this.state.activeregion]}`

Answer (score 2):

```
this.state.{this.state.activeregion}
```

This is not a valid JavaScript syntax, update it like below:

```js
this.state[this.state.activeregion]
```